# LINUX screen command - two video in same screen

Tags: unix, raspberry-pi, gnu-screen

I have ever same problem: i need to show 2 video in the same screen (from command line in unix).

on the web i find a tutorial (http://t3chadd1ct.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/omxplayer/), that solve my problem... using the *"screen command"*

> [...] This was solved easily by making use of the screen function. The
>   example below illustrates how to create a 2×2 matrix  [...]

```
screen
> -dmS camera1 sh -c 'omxplayer --win "0 0 960 540" rtsp://ip_address/live; exec bash' screen -dmS camera2 sh -c
> 'omxplayer --win "960 0 1920 540" rtsp://ip_address/live; exec bash'
> screen -dmS camera3 sh -c 'omxplayer --win "0 540 960 1080"
> rtsp://ip_address/live; exec bash' screen -dmS camera4 sh -c
> 'omxplayer --win "960 540 1920 1080" rtsp://ip_address/live; exec
> bash'
```

I've follow this tutorial but doesn't work correctly: my script execute only a video (the first one "camera2"):

```
more tmp01.sh 
#!/bin/sh

#1)this work:
#nohup omxplayer --win "0 0 1440 800" ../Shared/NO_LOGO_1/01.avi &
#nohup omxplayer --win "0 801 1440 900" ../Shared/NO_LOGO_1/02.avi &

#2)doesn't work
screen -dmS camera2 sh -c `omxplayer --win "0 0 200 200" /home/pi/Shared/NO_LOGO
_1/02_a.avi; exec bash`

screen -dmS camera1 sh -c `omxplayer --win "200 200 600 600" /home/pi/Shared/NO_
LOGO_1/01_a.avi; exec bash`
```

Where am I wrong???
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong kind of quotes.  Use `'` instead of the backquote (`` ` ``).  The way you are using it, the `screen` command won't terminate until the `omxplayer`'s output is complete (i. e. until that terminates.

```
screen -dmS camera2 sh -c 'omxplayer --win "0 0 200 200" /home/pi/Shared/NO_LOGO_1/02_a.avi; exec bash'
```

instead of

```
screen -dmS camera2 sh -c `omxplayer --win "0 0 200 200" /home/pi/Shared/NO_LOGO_1/02_a.avi; exec bash`
```

See the difference?

Comment: Yes! It Work Perfectly!I Lost a few a hours because i had not "screen function" in my raspberry. Now with your command work well!!! thank you!

Comment: And is possible to create an .sh like 
tmp.sh 
`#!/bin/sh omxplayer --win "0 0 200 200" /home/pi/Shared/NO_LOGO_1/02_a.avi`

and after some thing like =
screen -dmS camera2 sh tmp.sh
screen -dmS camera1 sh -c `omxplayer --win "200 200 600 600" /home/pi/Shared/NO_
LOGO_1/01_a.avi; exec bash` >>> a script with two screen instance and one of this use a sh script

Comment: If you create such a script, the first command (`omxplayer`) will be executed _and waited for_.  The next command (`screen`) will only be started after the `omxplayer` has terminated.  If you do it the other way 'round (first `screen`, then `omxplayer`), it will work because the `screen` command always terminates fast; it just starts a new screen window and in that the inner command runs in a detached fashion (because of option `-d`).

Comment: Btw, according to your resumé you haven't accepted any answer to any of your questions yet.  So I assume you probably do not know this:  If an answer solves your problem, you are supposed to _accept_ that (use the check mark left of the answer).  You can revoke accepts later and accept a different answer, but of course, a question with an accepted answer draws much less attention, so it is wise to wait before accepting.

Comment: I'm very sorry! Yes I accept the solution! It work perfectly! :D thank you one more time! :D

Comment: No problem, no harm done :)  You can accept answers even years later, so perhaps you want to review your old questions :)